# Computational Topology Paper

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, computational-topology

I am delving into the field of Computational Topology. I am aware of the books in this field, but could anybody tell me a nice relevant paper in this field which
tackles a "typical" Computational Topology problem?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "typical"? One which everyone is considering? One which everyone uses as an example? One which motivated the subject? One that your lecturer works on? etc.

Comment: One which everyone uses as an example

Comment: I don't know about tagging this computational-geometry, so I"m adding a computational-topology tag

Comment: It really depends on the flavour of computational topology you're interested in.  For example, computational 3-manifold topology -- things like the 3-sphere recognition algorithm -- have a very different flavour than say the Edelsbrunner / Harer text. 

Comment: Oh thanks I wasn't aware of this.
Yes I meant more the Edelsbrunner type.

Comment: Some of the references in answers to this question are relevant http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57975/reference-request-for-manifold-learning

Comment: The Stanford group has a preprints page.  Go there, there's many good examples.  For example: A. Zomorodian and G. Carlsson, “Localized homology” , Shape Modeling International , Lyon, France . Jan 2007 link

Comment: Your question is rather confusing.  The answer you accepted gives an example paper which is very much not of the sort you requested. 

Comment: @Ryan Budney Yes I realized this later too


Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the paper by Jeff Erickson and Pratik Worah,
"Computing the Shortest Essential Cycle,"
[*Discrete & Computational Geometry*,
Volume 44, Issue 4, December 2010](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1870895) ([PDF link](http://cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/pubs/pdf/essential.pdf)),
might serve your purposes.
They compute the shortest
"simple cycle that cannot be continuously deformed to a point or a single boundary."
The input to their problem 
is "a *combinatorial surface*, which is an abstract topological surface $M$ together with an edge-weighted graph $G$ cellularly embedded on $M$."
If $n$ is the complexity of the surface, their algorithm runs in $O(n^2 \log n)$ time,
and faster, $O( n \log n)$, when the genus and number of boundaries are considered fixed.
This paper is, in some sense, a culmination of a series of papers finding cycles on combinatorial
surfaces, often to cut them along the cycles to produces simpler surfaces.

            [image: Fig3]

Comment: This is nice. It harks back to the early days of Riemann surfaces, when 'connectedness' (=genus) was defined by curves along which one cut the surface.

Comment: Thanks you for the nice paper suggestion, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting books i know of are Edelsbrunner/Harer and Zomordian's thesis. On similar topics, the [Comtop group](http://comptop.stanford.edu/) at Stanford has very detailed information.